# Input dando resultados errados

Tags: php, javascript, html

eu tou fazendo uma loja com paypal, pagseguro e mercadopago, mas na hora da compra quando eu seleciono o input, ele sempre salva como mercadopago.

Controller

```php
    public function checkout()
    {
        if(!Security::ajax())
        {
            die();
        }

        $gateway = new Gateways();
        $gatewayData = $gateway->data();

        $gateway = $_POST['gateway'];

        $reference = $this->references->register();
```

html

```
<form class="row" method="post" id="checkout">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label><input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway" value="mercadopago" checked> MercadoPago</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway" value="pagseguro" > PagSeguro</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway" value="paypal"> PayPal</label><br>
        <br><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="terms" required> Eu aceito os <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termos">termos de compra</a></label>
    </div>
```

js

```
$('.checkout').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var terms = $('input[name=terms]').is(':checked');

    if (!terms) {
        alert('Aceite os termos!');
        return;
    }

    let gateway = $('input[name=gateway]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/carrinho/checkout',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            gateway: gateway
        },
        complete: function(result) {
            var res = JSON.parse(result.responseText);

            if (res.status) {
                location.href = res.link
            } else {
                alert(res.message);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

ele sempre resulta em mercadopago, eu nunca consigo colocar pelo paypal ou pagseguro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente seja porque você está usando um único `name="gateway"` para os três campos:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway" value="mercadopago" checked> MercadoPago</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway" value="pagseguro" > PagSeguro</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway" value="paypal"> PayPal</label><br>
```

Fazendo com que na hora do `jquery` pegar o valor em:

```
let gateway = $('input[name=gateway]').val();
```

Ele esteja pegando sempre a primeira ocorrência, sendo assim sugiro um loop para resolver de forma simples, por exemplo:

```
$('input[name=gateway]').each(function(){
    var ths = $(this);
    if(ths.prop("checked")){
        var gateway = ths.val();
    }
});
```

Que vai verificar todos os inputs com o `name="gateway"` e definir a variável `var gateway` apenas se estiver com a propriedade `checked=true`

> [Prop Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: Mas não importa oque eu coloco, sempre da o mesmo valor.

Se eu usar o input paypal, o resultado é mercado pago
se eu usar pagseguro, o resultado é mercado pag

Comment: Consegui arrumar, o valor foi

```var gateway = $('#gateway:checked').val();

```

Comment: usando seu código e a alteração que fiz deu certo, então era outro problema, vc estava usando provavelmente o id que deve ser único numa pagina, mas se conseguiu mto bem.